# Festival of Functional Regex Recursion - reconstruct particular string from this butchered one

Tags: c#, regex, recursion, functional-programming

In:

```
53_2_b
50
48_1_b_i
50A_3_b
48_1_b_iv
```

Out:

```
53(2)(b)
50
48(1)(b)(i)
50A(3)(b)
48(1)(b)(iv)
```

(They are section references from legislation which have been converted to NCNames. I want to unconvert them.)

Is there some embarrassingly small amount of code to do this, that will teach me plenty?

This is what I currently have:

```
readonly Func<char, bool> _isNotUnderscore = c => c != '_';

string ConvertFragmentToSecRef(string frag)
{           
    var p0 = new Regex(@"^[0-9]+[A-Z]*");
    var p1 = new Regex(@"[0-9]+");
    var p2 = new Regex(@"[\w]+");
    var p3 = new Regex(@"(i|v|x)+");

    var regexes = new[] {p0, p1, p2, p3};

    var sb = new StringBuilder();

    Recurse(frag,0,ref regexes,ref sb);

    return sb.ToString();
}

void Recurse(string left,int level, ref Regex[] regexes,ref StringBuilder sb)
{
    if (level < 4)
    {
        var head = String.Concat(left.TakeWhile(_isNotUnderscore));
        var tail = String.Concat(left.Skip(head.Count())).TrimStart('_');
        if (regexes[level].IsMatch(head))
        {
            sb.Append(level == 0 ? head : "(" + head + ")");
            Recurse(tail, level + 1, ref regexes, ref sb);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't need recursion for this, just [lookahead assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html):

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"_          # match _
    ([^_\r\n]*)  # match whatever follows except _ or newlines
    (?=[_\r]|$)  # assert that a _ or end-of-line follows", 
    "($1)", RegexOptions.Multiline | RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

This works on your multiline input string. Of course, if you have each line in a separate string, it's easier:

```
resultString = Regex.Replace(subjectString, 
    @"_      # match _
    ([^_]*)  # match whatever follows except _
    (?=_|$)  # assert that a _ or end-of-string follows", 
    "($1)", RegexOptions.IgnorePatternWhitespace);
```

Comment: Neat, but it doesn't generate the desired result (e.g. the third line looks like this: `48(1)(b)_i` instead of `48(1)(b)(i)`). Can you fine-tune this?

Comment: Ah, that might have to do with the .NET problem of matching `$` between `\r` and `\n` for whatever reason. Try the new version - does it work now?

Comment: Yes, this works now. Very interesting solution, I didn't know about lookahead/lookbehind assertions in regex until now. +1

Comment: This works great, thanks, what a neat little feature.  There are also negative lookahead and lookbehinds: http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2005/10/excluding-matches-with-regular-expressions.html

Comment: And here's the MSDN documentation: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/bs2twtah(v=VS.110).aspx